# Use Sublime Text find to highlight a regex group in search pattern

Tags: regex, text-editors, sublime-text

Is there a way to make *Sublime Text* highlight (match) only part of a regex search pattern?

For example, I want to exclusively highlight `Text` when searching for `Some(Text)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difficulty in getting a regex application to work will probably have a regex solution. In this case, [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

**Example using a lookbehind:**

- Sample:

  ```
  SomeText
  ```
- Regex:

  ```
  (?<=Some)(Text)
  ```
- Match:

  ```
  Text
  ```

Comment: In order to match `(Text)`, you need to escape the parentheses so the regex should be `(?<=Some)\(Text\)`

Comment: @NonlinearFruit as I interpret OP's intention, that's the regex put in search box, thus this solution is probably correct, no reason to downvote it

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

`(?<=preceeding_enclosing_text)your_searched_text(?=following_enclosing_text)`

In your particular example:

`(?<=Some\().+?(?=\))`